# Need Help Debugging JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, joomla

I'm quite new to JQuery and would really appreciate a hand trying to debug. I'm trying to use Anything Slider on a site. I've got the slider working fine on a plain test html document, but I can't for the life of me get it working in Joomla (where the site is hosted) This is on a custom page that we've developed and plugged into Joomla, but that shouldn't make a difference.

I'm getting a

> TypeError: $(...).anythingSlider is not a function

in Chrome and Firefox inspectors, I've read that this could be caused by JQuery, but the last JQuery scripts to load are the ones for the slider as far as I'm aware. I've also used the bog standard Joomla template to alleviate issues with scripts being imported in ours.

Here's the URL http://dev.turn2me.org/thought-catcher
Ignore the messy layout, that's just me testing the default template

If anyone could have a look and see what it is it would be much much appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: I count two separate versions of jQuery, as well as several `404 not found` errors. Please check your console...

Comment: Don't load jQuery twice. It'll screw things up – like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your http://dev.turn2me.org/js/js/validation_registration.js file isn't being loaded.  Also, you're getting 404s on several images so it looks like you have resource path issues. My first guess would be that the `/js/js` part isn't right.

Comment: Ah yes sorry you're right! There was an extra Jquery being imported down the bottom of the page that I didn't see! Please excuse my ignorance, it's been a long night! Thanks again for you help, that sorted it!

Answer (score 0):

remove line 889 you are loading jquery twice - when I copied all of anythingSlider.js into firebug and made the call afterwards it worked
  src="/flot/jquery/jquery.js">
you are loading jquery 1.5 here

either that or load the anythingslider.js at bottom of page